# Console output is not aligned

Tags: c, linux, bash, embedded, embedded-linux

My embedded system has one background program which generates some output message to console. 
When it's not finished, the login program starts and prompt login string to same console as well.

My question is, when the login prompt string comes out, the output message generated by the background program is not aligned like this:

---

```
Embedded System login: msg_line1...
                                   msg_line2...
                                               msg_line3...
```

The expected output should be:

---

```
Embedded System login: msg_line1...
msg_line2...
msg_line3...
msg_line4...
```

---

Have no idea how to resolve the problem...
Could anyone help?

THX!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure your terminal program to autolinefeed, so that it generates the `\r` internally whenever it receives a `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

use a redirection for your background program

```
YourBackStuff.sh >/tmp/back_out.1 2>/tmp/Back_out.2 &
```

or refresh the screen.

Notice that only the appearance is modified, the real output ou current application/shell (so not the background one) is correct, only the terminal show your all the info received. So

```
YourFrontApp.sh | tee /tmp/front_out.1
cat /tmp/front_out.1
```

will produce a correct display (when background process stop)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your messages are sent with a new-line character (represented by `\n` in C) at the end of each line.  This requests a new line from the terminal, which it duly provides.  It does not request a carriage return (i.e. "go back to the left hand edge").  This would be represented in C as a `\r`.

To fix it, you need to set your terminal application to interpret `\n` as `\n\r` - it will have a setting for "treat newlines as newline+CR" or some such.